# DNX on VSO Host Build Controller

Tags: asp.net-core, tfsbuild, azure-devops, dnx

When trying to build an ASP.NET 5 DNX project on VSO, I get the following error:

> Cannot find DNX runtime dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta6 in the folder:
>   C:\Users\buildguest.dnx\runtimes (119,5): Error : The Dnx Runtime
>   package needs to be installed. See output window for more details.

Does this mean that we cannot use the host build controller with DNX projects yet?

Comment: You can install DNX using NuGet with a custom build script.

Comment: @HenkMollema: I have done this by adding a powershell script build step.  Now it seems that package restore doesn't work with DNX projects. Would it be best to manually restore from DNU using powershell?

Comment: Yes, you could take a look at the build scripts Microsoft is using themselves.

Comment: @HenkMollema: Where would I find something like this?  When running "dnu restore" on the VSO build controller, I just get _"The term 'dnu' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program."_

Comment: See the `build.cmd` script on any aspnet repository.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found a great guide on how to install dnx on vso host.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/azure/deploy-aspnet5

Added the first PreBuild.ps1 script as a Powershell build step and it worked right away.

Comment: I downvoted this because link-only answers are not good answers -- links tend to die, then this answer becomes useless. If you summarize the exact steps that are provided in the link I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: Now that DNX is obsolete, the link is dead. No luck with Web Archive either @DanielMann

Answer (score 0):

Since I still use it, to compile my code, to me, it's not dead.

I integrated some travis-ci config in py project, have a look at my [.travis.yml](https://github.com/pazof/yavsc/blob/vnext/.travis.yml) for an update, but I count on my host name, my pc, and my internet connection to serve it as I do since few years:

[dnx-install.sh](https://lua.pschneider.fr/files/Paul/dnx-install.sh)

Note that DNX should be able to build DNX, 
from it's source code, even marked as obsolete, and that It would be possible, but painfull, to write some scripts and use `mono-roslyn` directly ... still not a dead branch to me.